# $(this).parent().remove() in angularjs version

Tags: angularjs

I am a new in AngularJS. I want to do something very similar to jquery's syntax's removing a parent div. Something like:

```
$(this).parent().remove()
```

My whole code is currently:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>

        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
            <br>
            Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

            <div>
            <button ng-click="Sample()">DEAN</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.firstName = "John";
            $scope.lastName = "Doe";
            $scope.Sample = function(){
                $(this).parent().remove()
            };
        });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to hide the button on click ?

Comment: What you want to remove?

Comment: I want that div element that acts as a parent to the button removed. Since that div will be removed the button will be removed as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>

        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
            <br>
            Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

            <div>
            <button ng-click="Sample($event)">DEAN</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.firstName = "John";
            $scope.lastName = "Doe";
            $scope.Sample = function(event){
                angular.element(event.target).parent().remove();
            };
        });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Changes:**

Add $event parameter:

```
<button ng-click="Sample($event)">DEAN</button>
```

And update your Sample() function:

```
$scope.Sample = function(event){
    angular.element(event.target).parent().remove();
};
```

Comment: PERFECT ANSWER! Thanks!

Comment: Does that event syntax apply to other jquery functions as well? like .find() or .text()?

Comment: Yes, it's jqLite object, lightweight alternative for jQuery. Follow here for more information: [link](https://gist.github.com/esfand/9638882) and see list of supported jQuery functions

Comment: Wow Great! So this is hpw that jQlite work, it has no proper examples. I'm happy to see one from you

Comment: I'm recently activated on social networks. If you like, you can connect to me as a friend [linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/in/mbnsoft)

Comment: Oh sure! What's your account in LinkedIn?

Answer (score 1):

To implement any logic tied on some view element in [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) you need to create dedicated [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) with appropriate functionality.

For example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('buttonToRemove', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        template: '<div><button ng-click="sample()">DEAN</button></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {   
           scope.sample = function() {
              element.remove();
           }
        }
      };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <button-to-remove />
</html>
```

**P.S:** it'd be easier for you to specify `templateUrl` and keep layout for this button in separated file instead of keeping all your markup related to that directive in the string format.

Answer (score 1):

In Html DOM

```
<div remove-on-click>
      <button ng-click="Sample()">DEAN</button>
</div>
```

Outside the controlloler

```
app.directive('removeOnClick', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.Sample= function() {
                element.html('');
            };
        }
    }
});
```